# Execution failed for task ':flutter_inappwebview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, flutter, gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Warning: Mapping new ns http:/schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http:/schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http:/schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http:/schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http:/schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http:/schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http:/schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http:/schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http:/schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http:/schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':flutter_inappwebview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_inappwebview:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not download okhttp-3.14.9.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9)
> > Could not get resource 'https:/repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.14.9/okhttp-3.14.9.jar'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https:/repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.14.9/okhttp-3.14.9.jar'.
> > No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https:/help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 42s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Warning: Mapping new ns http:/schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http:/schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http:/schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http:/schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http:/schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http:/schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http:/schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http:/schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http:/schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http:/schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':flutter_inappwebview:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_inappwebview:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not download okhttp-3.14.9.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.9)
> > Could not get resource 'https:/repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.14.9/okhttp-3.14.9.jar'.
> > Could not HEAD 'https:/repo*maven.apache.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.14.9/okhttp-3.14.9.jar'.
> > repo.maven.apache.org

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https:/help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 0):

what helps me:

in: `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`
update to: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip`

in: `android/build.gradle`
update to:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'